# Why does this print an empty list and dictionary?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

data = {
    0:{
        0:"title",
        1:"dates",
        2:"city/state",
        3:"country"
    },
    1:{
        0:"event",
        1:"reps",
        2:"prize"
    },
    2:{
        0:"results"
    }
}


url = "https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search.php?org_id=KCBA"
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features='lxml')
all_data = []
for element in soup.find_all('div', class_="row"):
    event = {}
    for i, col in enumerate(element.find_all('div', class_='col-md-4')):
        for j, item in enumerate(col.strings):
            event[data[i][j]] = item
    all_data.append(event)

print(json.dumps(all_data,indent=4))
```

heres a link to the website https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search.php?org_id=KCBA

Im unsure why nothing gets added to the list and dictionaries

Comment: `url= 'https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search_ol_json.php?otype=TEXT&evr_map_type=2&org_id=KCBA&evr_begin=6/16/2022&evr_end=7/16/2022&evr_address=&evr_radius=50&evr_type=269&evr_openings=0&evr_region=&evr_region_type=1&evr_judge=0&evr_keyword=&evr_rep_name='`

Comment: As with your previous question the url needs to be constructed correctly. The rest of the code can remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To simulate the Ajax request you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = "https://mms.kcbs.us/members/evr_search_ol_json.php"

params = {
    "otype": "TEXT",
    "evr_map_type": "2",
    "org_id": "KCBA",
    "evr_begin": "6/16/2022",
    "evr_end": "7/16/2022",
    "evr_address": "",
    "evr_radius": "50",
    "evr_type": "269",
    "evr_openings": "0",
    "evr_region": "",
    "evr_region_type": "1",
    "evr_judge": "0",
    "evr_keyword": "",
    "evr_rep_name": "",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser"
)


data = {
    0: {0: "title", 1: "dates", 2: "city/state", 3: "country"},
    1: {0: "event", 1: "reps", 2: "prize"},
    2: {0: "results"},
}

all_data = []
for element in soup.find_all("div", class_="row"):
    event = {}
    for i, col in enumerate(element.find_all("div", class_="col-md-4")):
        for j, item in enumerate(col.strings):
            event[data[i][j]] = item
    all_data.append(event)

print(json.dumps(all_data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "Frisco BBQ Challenge",
        "dates": "6/16/2022 - 6/18/2022",
        "city/state": "Frisco, CO 80443",
        "country": "UNITED STATES",
        "event": "STATE CHAMPIONSHIP",
        "reps": "Reps: BUNNY TUTTLE, RICH TUTTLE, MICHAEL WINTER",
        "prize": "Prize Money: $13,050.00",
        "results": "Results Not In"
    },
    {
        "title": "York County BBQ Festival",
        "dates": "6/17/2022 - 6/18/2022",
        "city/state": "Delta, PA 17314",
        "country": "UNITED STATES",
        "event": "STATE CHAMPIONSHIP",
        "reps": "Reps: ANGELA MCKEE, ROBERT MCKEE, LOUISE WEIDNER",
        "prize": "Prize Money: $5,500.00",
        "results": "Results Not In"
    },


...and so on.
```

Comment: could you point me to a source that would explain the changes to the url?

Comment: @ClayH You will see the Api URL in Chrome Developer Tools (or Firefox Developer Tools) if you click on Network Tab and refresh the page. The page will load the data from it and you will see the required params as well.